# Function to erase a character in a string

Tags: c, strings

```
void chrrem (char arr[], size_t len, size_t pos)
{
    memmove(arr + pos, arr + (pos + 1), (len - pos) + 1);
}
```

It is supposed to be just fast.
Erases the character pointed by `pos` (starting from 0)

---

Note that this function works with a statically allocated array like so:

> ```
> char arr [256] = "Mystring";
>
> // >>
> chrrem (arr, strlen(arr), 0);
> chrrem (arr, strlen(arr), 0);
>
> printf(arr);
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> sring
> ```

Comment: If you need to call this in a loop, it's a mistake. Rather, you want to erase *all* of them as you go instead of repeatedly copying the tail. Your question would be more on-topic if it showed *how* you use this function.

Comment: @nhgrif That's how the function works for me though. I will clarify that it has to be a statically allocated array.

Comment: @nhgrif I understand how it *can* be called, what matters for the review is how it *will* be called.

Comment: @o11c Perhaps write a review then.  It's not the fault of the function itself is being used incorrectly though.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on the meta.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5732/36366)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not a [c](/questions/tagged/c) programmer, and I know short, cryptic function and variable names are used in [c](/questions/tagged/c) for historical reasons, but I'll still comment that I don't like it one bit.  I'd name the function `removeCharacter`.

---

Given that the function is only intended to be used on c-strings, is the `len` parameter actually necessary?  Can't we eliminate that parameter and get the `len` in the same way your context code demonstrates calculating a c-string's length?

```
void removeCharacter(char string[], size_t index) {
     memmove(string+index, string + index + 1, strlen(string) - pos + 1);
}
```

Now we can actually justify the function wrapping the `memmove`.  It makes it easier to use because all we have to do now is pass our string and the index of the character we want removed.

---

Given the performance implications of moving memory like this, it might be a great idea to offer a companion function which allows the user to remove a range of characters.

```
void removeSubstring(char string[], size_t index, size_t length) {
    memmove(string+index, string+index+length, strlen(string)-index+1);
}
```

<sub>I think it'd certainly be worthwhile to have a `Range` struct which has an `index` and `length` member, and simply pass this struct as the second argument instead of the `index` and `length` arguments.</sub>

---

And of course, it's important to be sure your code is well documented so that users are clear on exactly what they're getting with the function.

Also, this seems like a pretty easy thing to unit tests for, so be sure to do that.

Comment: We could change strlen( string)-index to strlen(string+index), and then string and index only appear as string+index, so you could do away with the index argument and provide a function that removes just the first character, removeFirstCharacter say, and then your removeCharacter is removeFirstCharacter( string+index). Similarly for removeSubstring.

Comment: `removeFirstCharacter(char string[]) { removeCharacter(string, 0) }`  You could also do a `removeLastCharacter(char string[])` function. `removeLastCharacter(char string[]) { string[strlen(string)] = '\0' }`

Comment: It would be nice if the function could determine that the `pos` is out of range (at least in debug builds, but preferably for all builds), and return an error. Not doing so is what makes so many C standard library functions so dangerous. You could mess things up pretty badly by passing in an out-of-range `pos`.

Answer (score 3):

There are not many ways to optimize the function by speed.

So about style:

```
char arr[]
arr + pos
```

looks inconsistent. If you don't address it as array, then why bother?

Second, most string and mem functions have the string length limit at the end of the parameter list - strncpy, strncat, memcmp, ...so I would switch the position of len and pos.

Third, most string functions return a pointer to the "new" string. I would therefore return the pointer to the resulting string, instead of void. This gives a caller more flexibility and in case you decide to implement error-checking one day, you can actually return NULL. Of course, the function will be slightly slower then.

Finally, I don't like the idea of putting strlen() into the function, because the caller will not be able to benefit from the knowledge about the string.

```
char bla[] = "MyString";
chrrem(bla, sizeof(bla) - 1, 0);
```

and you don't need to loop through the string to find the end any longer.

Answer (score 3):

You copy one more char than needed. `len - pos` gives the tail including the terminating `\0`.

For example, your first call is with `len` = 8 and `pos` = 0. You need to copy the last 7 characters + `\0`, in total 8.

Another example, if you called with `pos` 4 giving `"MySting"`, you need to copy `"ing"`, in total 4. With `len` = 8 and `pos` = 4, the result is `len - pos` giving 4.